# Configuration for a logging function

Tags: c, logging, global-variables

I wrote a simple logging function which displays a timestamp and uses `vprintf()` to emulate `printf()`. Now, my main program is reading a configuration file into a `struct configuration`. I plan on making the logging function use this configuration to determine where it should log to (std{out,err}, syslog, some other file, ...). So, what would be the best way to make my logging function know where it should log to? I'm thinking of making my `struct configuration * config` a global variable, declared just before `main()` and having `extern struct configuration * config` in log.h so that log.c can use it. But everybody keeps on saying "global variables are bad, don't use them" so I'd like to know if there's a better way to do it.

Comment: I'd definitely create a global variable in the source file of my config class and declare that extern in the header (not a pointer to a instance but a global instance). Never had a problem with this. You only need to give it a name that is unique enough to avoid collisions since you are in global namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, global configuration needs to be global. So, I would consider that an exception to the rule. However, you may want to expose the `struct` as `const` in most cases. That would help narrow down what modules are changing the global state in the future.

To accomplish this, use a global function that exposes a `const` pointer instead of a direct `extern`. In fact, you could declare the configuration `struct` as `static` as well. That would further eliminate unexpected access.

Answer (score 0):

If this logging configuration does (and always will) apply for the whole system at any time, then this would be one of the few times when a global variable is OK to use, imho.

You should consider whether you need the whole configuration struct global, or just the logging config value.